# C# MVVM как взаимодействовать с элементами

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть у меня ViewModel класс который описывает логику взаимодействия, и в нём есть одно поле к которому биндится кнопка/TextBox, как мне повлиять на состояние кнопки/textBox, сделать их красной/неактивным?

Comment: Ну... Сделать свой стиль?  
Неактивными сделать еще проще, привяжите св-во IsEnabled к bool переменной, например

Comment: У меня есть кнопка, на которую жмёшь в первый раз она должна стать красной, жмёшь второй раз зелёной, в третий, белой.И так по кругу. Это можно сделать через стиль?

Comment: Покажите описание взаимодействия и как биндите

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос исчерпан. Т.к только начал изучать MVVM, не сразу дошло что любые property можно биндить. Вот как я решил: Отрывок из VM

```
 SolidColorBrush _color = Brushes.Black;
    public SolidColorBrush color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set
        {
            _color = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("color");
        }
    }
```

Отрывок из XAML:

```
  <Button Background="{Binding color}" Content="Проиграть" FontSize="14" Margin="4"/>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут одно замечание, цвет - это View слой и если есть возможность избавиться от него в VM слое, то это стоит сделать. Как? Ну например завести свойство статуса объекта, по которой с помощью триггера в View будет задаваться нужный цвет.

Comment: Ещё один способ избавиться от цвета, использовать конвертер